# Как в строке определить количество слов длины k без использования циклов?

Tags: c++, строки, stl

Дана строка, где слова разделены пробелами и двоеточиями. Нужно посчитать количество слов длиной меньше k и вернуть контейнер этих слов. Циклами пользоваться запрещено, разрешены только STL алгоритмы и контейнеры. Нет даже представления, как это всё можно сделать. Мне бы хотя бы идею.

Comment: Напишите сначала без алгоритмов, используя циклы, потом переведите на алгоритмы.

Comment: Разделены пробелами и двоеточиями - вот так - word : word : word или как?

Comment: есть алгоритм for_each -  а это как бы цикл. дальше все должно быть просто

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решение возможно неоптимальное, но всё же:
Пишете следующую рекурсивную функцию:
Ищете с помощью `std::find()` в строке двоеточие ил пробел, нашли - с помощью `std::substr()` берёте все подстроку до этого символа, если ее длина меньше `k`, `push_back()` ее в вектор. Из исходной строки удаляете это двоеточие/пробел. Далее вызываете это функцию снова, если длина строки > 0. Правда на больших строках такое, скорее всего, не пройдет по времени (можно попробовать кэшировать функцию, это сильно ускоряет процесс).

Answer (score -1):

Вот поиск символьной комбинации в стандартном потоке ввода, не через циклы `while`, а с использованием предиката и алгоритма `std::find_if`. Предлагаю такой вариант решения:

```
std::find_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             Predicate());
```

где `Predicate()` вызов конструктора класса Predicate с определенным оператором ().

Предикат Вы можете реализовать для проверки того, является ли считанный объект словом, а не двоеточием (хотя из вопроса не до конца ясно, как именно разделены слова, приведите конкретный пример), и, если является словом, то проверить его длину. Смотрите класс `string` и функцию-член `length()`, например.

Пример реализации класса `Predicate`:

```
// глобальными эти переменные не стоит делать, хотя бы в namespace надо их засунуть

std::uint64_t counter = 0;            // счетчик всех слов в вводимом тексте
std::map<std::string, int> container; // ключ - слово, значение - кол-во копий

class Predicate
{
    Predicate() {}
    void operator()(const std::string & str) // предполагается ввод word : word : word и т.д.
    {
        if (str != “:” && str.length() < k)
        {
            ++counter;
            ++container[str];
        }
    }
};
```

Еще дам пример использования `std::istream_iterator`. Считывание данных с итератором:

```
if (iit != eos) str = *iit;
++iit;
```

где `iit` - это `std::istream_iterator<string>`, а `eos` - итератор того же типа, означающий конец ввода. Вы легко сможете найти в интеренете информацию по использованным в моем ответе возможностям C++, см. [этот сайт](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/) и [этот сайт](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Answer (score -1):

Первое, что приходит в голову по вашей задаче:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <list>

std::list<std::string> result;
std::string str;
int size = /*Необходимая длина*/

struct Func 
{
    Func() {}
    void operator()(char & letter) 
    {
        if (!str.empty())
        {
            if (letter == ':' || letter == ' ')
            {
                size_t pos = str.find_first_of(":");
                std::string temp = str.substr(0, pos);
                if (temp.length() < size) { result.push_back(temp); }
                str.erase(0, pos + 1);
            }
            else if (str.find_first_of(":") == std::string::npos)
            {
                std::string temp = str.substr(0, str.length());
                if (temp.length() < size) { result.push_back(temp); }
                str.clear();
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()

{
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), Func());
    /*Далее работа с контейнером result*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот такой кусок кода вызовет объект `f` со всеми словами из строки `s`

```
std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::istringstream(s)), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), f);
```

Проблемы две: 
1. Слова выделяются по стандартным пробельным символам, поэтому проще всего перед вызовом заменить в строке двоеточия на пробелы.
2. `f` не просто функция, а должна "куда-то" вернуть контейнер и количество, поэтому придется сделать класс, инициализирующийся ссылкой на контейнер, с членом `operator ()( std::string &s)`, который проверит длину строки и пополнит контейнер.

Answer (score -2):

Я делал бы так, создаю стек, прохожусь итератором по строке, каждую букву записываю в стек, вижу пробел или двоеточие, смотрю стек, добавляю в контейнер слово из стека если оно подходит, чищу стек и т.д.

Comment: @JeeOpp чаще всего небольшой фрагмент кода намного нагляднее словесного описания.